# How to get a list of the elements in column A that are not in column B of dataframe in apache spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have 2 datafame X,Y. X has column A, Y have column B. A,B has type string. 
How to get a list of the elements in column A that are not in column B??

Or I have a string S and I want to check if S is an element in column A. How to check??

please help me!! :(
I code in scala!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question (filter all elements within DataFrame X that are not in DataFrame Y):

```
val X = Seq("1", "2", "3", "4", "5").toDF("A")
val Y = Seq("4", "5", "6", "7", "8").toDF("B")

X.except(Y).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+
|  A|
+---+
|  3|
|  1|
|  2|
+---+
```

Your second question (checking if string S exists in column A in DataFrame X):

```
val lookFor = "3"
assert(X.where(s"A == '$lookFor'").count() > 0)
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: thanks for your anwser! but in the second question, if use .count() spend very much time :(

Comment: You have to have an Action in order to catalyze the pipeline (of Transformations) and count() is the cheapest one there is

Comment: it spent too much time!!